# 555_BJT_EE flip flop not working

Tags: led, flipflop

I'm trying to turn on the LED with a tactile switch but not sure if this will work?

Can someone please have any suggestions?
[image: Example circuit]

Comment: That's a very unusual configuration for a 555. Can you explain how you think it's supposed to work?

Comment: why the 555? this isn't a job for a timer IC. A single transistor *latch* would do, be much easier, use none of the current… (your BJT 555 will use a lot more current than your LEDs, which is pretty unnecessary. Generally, if the answer is "555", the question better involve "educational circuit for illustration of something you don't do in production)

Comment: Seems you're trying to do more than just turn on an LED.  What actual function are you trying to accomplish with the 555 in the circuit?  Refer to the LM555 data sheet for examples of using the chip.  https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf?ts=1688468508803&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM555%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Dasc-null-null-GPN_EN-cpc-pf-google-wwe%2526utm_content%253DLM555%2526ds_k%253DLM555%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DEAIaIQobChMIzZPTqfP0_wIVEUBIAB0pAQG3EAAYAiAAEgJVpfD_BwE%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds

Comment: Reset must be connected to 5V.  I think you have CV and TRIG confused.  Where did you get the circuit because it has issues.  And there are simpler ways to make a switch turn on a LED.

Comment: Thanks you all for the feedback. Yes, not sure what i am doing. I'm trying to do a push button circuit that latches the LEDS on and off. for example, one push on, one push off.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faqvYt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The addition of the transistors fully turns on and off alternating LEDs.