# Having trouble driving load from a 555 timer via a transistor

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I'm trying to use a 555 timer to drive an output in pulses. The circuit I've come up with is:
[image: 555 and Transistor]

- The Reset Pin of the 555 will be driven by another circuit (not shown for simplicity)
- Once I've got everything working I'm going to replace D3 and R5 with a buzzer

I've built this on some breadboard, and it *almost* works - If I remove the transistor D2 flashes on and off as I would expected.

However when I put the transistor back in D2 and D3 don't flash on and off. Instead they have a dim light and a bright light.

I've no idea what would cause this or what to do to fix it. I've tried changing the values of R4 and R5 but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Do you want D2 and D3 to both turn on (emit light) at the same time, or D2 turns on when D3 turns off and vice versa?

Comment: Also, you are missing the decoupling capacitor for your NE555! Please also tell us what your supply voltage is.

Comment: Did you mean to use a PNP transistor as an emitter follower? Did you want an NPN instead? Did you want a common emitter configuration instead?

Comment: @MArcus Muller, I'm going to be using 5V. A decoupling capacitor wasn't something I'd considered. What value would you recommend?

Comment: @Sotto Voce, I would like both LEDs to be on at the same time. I know this is a bit pointless, but I'm building up the circuit in steps. D2 is supposed to be the output of the 555. D3 is just the load. I suspect the buzzer will draw too much power from the 555 so I want to use the transistor to drive it.

Comment: @entropy 5V is too low for an NE555

Comment: @entropy you will hence either need to use a different IC (there's much less bad CMOS variants of the 555, TLC555 etc), and these will come with a datasheet with recommended capacitors. Not hard! (I'm a bit curious what the "driven by another circuit" is – I smell a strong sense of "this would already be easier if done with a microcontroller" here, but that's just speculation)

Comment: @entropy I think I already posted some kind of appropriate-related circuit [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/675048/330261).

Comment: @entropy my impression is that you're using a PNP device for Q1 where an NPN device would seem to be the better choice.

Comment: @Marcus Muller, the exact part I'm using is a NE555P. According to https://www.ti.com/product/NE555/part-details/NE555P 5V is the minimum supply. As somebody with more experience then me, is a higher voltage recommended? Right now I've got my prototype running from a USB supply, but my plan is to use a 9V battery and a voltage regulator to provide a stable 5V

Comment: @periblepsis, Thank you, that circuit is exactly what I need to see - I'm going to use the plagiarist school of design!

Comment: @Sotto Voce, and Math Keeps Me Busy, You are right - I really should have used a PNP transistor and this the root cause of the problem. I used the wrong type because that was all I could find and tried to make it work (I know, in hindsight that was a stupid thing to do). Because of your suggestions I've 'borrowed' NPN from another project, and now it's working as expected. At least I'm a little wiser now

Comment: @entropy the NE555 uses so much current for standby that your 9V battery will not last very long. In all honesty, let go of the NE555. The 555 CMOS variants are better in *every* aspect, and there's really no reason to burn through expensive batteries to save 10ct on an IC, if at all. Regarding 5V supply: see "high-level output voltage" in the table on page 4. You're burning nearly half of your supply voltage in the NE555P. The rest might or might not be enough to drive your loads.

Comment: @Marcus Müller - the upstream circuit is actually nothing more sophisticated than another 555 timer that is triggered from a couple of switches. I've set it up as a simple delay circuit that I can vary using a pot, before triggers the second 555. And as I say the second 555 creates a pulse which I'll use to drive the buzzer. IMHO a microcontroller is probably overkill for something so simple, but it's a good question

Comment: that sounds way complicated to me, and a microcontroller is definitely not overkill. Your shown circuit has the NE555 + three external components to just configure the NE555. So, that's three more components than a microcontroller solution would need – and that microcontroller solution would also implement the delay, generate a square wave for a buzzer, read the potentiometer… All that probably at < 1mA during operations and in the region of a 3.7V lithium battery's self-discharge current when sleeping.

Comment: @Marcus Müller. Thanks for the advice. It sounds to me like I need to order some CMOS 555 timers, and since I need to order some PNP transistors any way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collector-base junction of a transistor is a PN junction, basically a diode. With a PNP transistor the collector acts like the anode, the base like the cathode. In your circuit it's like putting a diode from the positive supply to LED D2, so that one probably lights brightly. At the same time D2 and R4 are pulling the base low to some degree, which might be enough to turn the transistor on partially, letting D3 light dimly. The transistor has it's collector to positive, emitter to ground, this is backwards from what you usually see for a PNP. You're probably going to need to find another circuit to drive the LEDs.

Comment: based on your reply, I've moved D3 and R5 so that they now sit between the 5V rail and the Collector. The good news is that the LEDs no longer change brightness. The bad news is that D3 comes on when it should be off and visa-versa!

Comment: Of course the D3 LED turns on and off backwards because your PNP transistor with D3 and R5 at the collector is an inverter. But now the base current of the transistor is EXTREMELY high without a series resistor to limit the base current.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've accepted it as explains what was happening.